# How to fix 'The type name could not be found' after upgrading an ASP.NET project from .NET Core 3.0 to 3.1?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

After upgrading an ASP.NET project from .NET Core 3.0 to .NET Core 3.1 I get the following error when trying to run `dotnet publish --release Configuration` on a production server.

```
error CS1069: The type name 'FileIOPermission' could not be found in the namespace
'System.Security.Permissions'. This type has been forwarded to assembly
'System.Security.Permissions, Version=4.0.3.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' Consider adding a reference to that assembly.
```

The project compiles fine through Visual Studio 2019 on my development machine.

The .csproj looks like this (redacted rulesets and some `<ItemGroup>`s related to T4 templates):

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>

    ...

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="dapper" Version="1.60.9" />
        <PackageReference Include="dapper.sqlbuilder" Version="1.60.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.2.3" />
        <PackageReference Include="System.CodeDom" Version="4.5.0" />
    </ItemGroup>


    ...

</Project>
```

I have Visual Studio Build Tools 2017 and 2019 installed on the production server.

Changing the .csproj back to `<TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>` everything works fine.

Comment: Could it be that you need to install the relevant NuGet package first? The latest is version 4.7.0 (not 4.0.3): https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Security.Permissions/#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had installed the .NET Core 3.1.102 SDK separately. Uninstalling that and falling back to the version that comes with Visual Studio Build Tools 2019 fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem while creating a new .NET 5.0 class library project with Visual Studio 2019.  A solution: install System.Security.Permissions nuget package published by microsoft.

[image]